# Is it possible to disable a certain type of error with Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

Recently, I changed all of the function declarations for my components from this:

```
function LoginButton(props) {
    const {style, iconStyle, type, onPress} = props;
}
```

to this:

```
function LoginButton({style, iconStyle, type, onPress}) {
}
```

Before, I wasn't getting any errors from Flow. Now, it's giving me `Missing type annotation for destructuring. Flow(InferError)` for all of them.

As there are a lot of these declarations, I don't want to prefix all of them with `// $FlowFixMe` because it looks messy. I know that I can add `: any` at the end of the destructuring expressions to fix all of these, but that also looks messy. I would prefer to disable all Flow errors of this kind for my project from the `.flowconfig` file; is there a way to do this?

Comment: if you remove `// @flow` from the very top of a file, flow will ignore it

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there's no way to ignore a specific error on a broad scale. Doing so would be incredibly unsound especially in this case.

I understand your frustration, but one thing to keep in mind is that `$FlowFixMe` *should* look messy because it *is* messy. `$FlowFixMe` should almost always be a temporary solution, as the goal should always be to fix the underlying type issue (hence the "FixMe" part of `$FlowFixMe`).

Any `$FlowFixMe` introduces unsoundness, it basically turns off the type system, and hiding that from developers is almost always a bad idea. If you want to continue with strongly type code, and you want the safety provided by that, then you're gonna need to start explicitly typing your functions.